# ¿Cómo puedo abrir varios archivos con "with open"?

Tags: python

Trato de abrir múltiples archivos con `with open` para enviar de manera automatizada por selemium a mis alumnos, las boletas de sus calificaciones (entiendo que existen otros medios más simplificados como smtp, pero yo lo quiero hacer por selenium).

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
with open(r"{}".format(ruta),"r") as f, open(r"{}".format(correos_alumnos),"r") as f1, open(r"{}".format(codigo_alumnos),"r") as f2:
                 
    for line in f.readlines(), line_correos in f1.readlines(), line_codigos in f2.readlines():
        line, line_correos, line_codigos = line.rstrip("\n")[:40], line_correos.rstrip("\n")[:400], line_codigos.rstrip("\n")[:9]
```

Cuando uno solo dos archivos con `with open`, todo sale correcto y se puede ejecutar, pero al unir tres o más, se genera un errror: `for line in f.readlines(), line_correos in f1.readlines(), line_codigos in f2.readlines():` `NameError: name 'line_correos' is not defined`.

Se supone que `line_correos` es la variable que cuenta las iteraciones del ciclo, puesto que ya está definida, no logro entender por qué me salta ese error.

¿Existe alguna forma de leer simultáneamente tres o más archivos de txt con `with open`? De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está en el `with`, que es correcto, sino en el `for`.

En un `for` no puedes especificar varios bucles "en paralelo" como lo que estás intentando hacer. Al menos no directamente. `for` espera un solo iterable. Ahora bien, con ayuda de funciones como `zip()` puedes juntar varios iterables en uno solo. Por ejemplo:

```
for line, line_correos, line_codigos in zip(f.readlines(), f1.readlines(), f2.readlines()):
```

En este caso `zip()` recibe una serie de iterables (tres en este caso). En cada iteración del `for`, `zip()` devolverá una tupla (con tres elementos en este caso), en el que cada elemento de la tupla ha sido tomado de cada uno de los iterables. Eso te permite iterar "en paralelo" en los tres ficheros a la vez.

Ten en cuenta que cuando uno de los iterables que le pasas a `zip()` se agote, `zip()` dará por terminado el bucle. Es decir, en tu caso el bucle terminará cuando se acabe **el fichero más corto**. Si los tres tienen la misma longitud no hay problema. De lo contrario te habrán quedado datos sin procesar en alguno de los otros ficheros.

En el módulo `itertools` dispones de la función `zip_longest()` que funciona igual que `zip()` sólo que no se detiene cuando uno de los iterables se agota, sino que empieza a devolver `None` para los valores de ese iterable y sigue con los otros, deteniéndose sólo cuando se hayan agotado todos. En vez de `None` puedes especificar otro valor por defecto para los que se vayan agotando.

### Ampliación de la respuesta

La función `readlines()` de un fichero lee el fichero completo en memoria, creando como resultado una lista en la que cada elemento es una línea. Si los ficheros son muy grandes, estas listas ocuparán mucho espacio en memoria. De hecho pudiera darse el caso de que los ficheros fuesen tan grandes que las listas no entraran en la memoria disponible en cuyo caso el bucle anterior no podría ejecutarse.

Sin embargo `zip()` no necesita que le pases listas. Basta que le pases *iterables*. Un iterable es cualquier objeto sobre el cual se pueda iterar (básicamente que implemente el método `__next__()`). En particular los ficheros devueltos por `open()` (como `f`, `f1` o `f2`) son iterables. Cada vez que iteras sobre un fichero, el iterador lee la siguiente línea y te la devuelve.

Esto implica que el bucle se podría haber escrito también así:

```
for line, line_correos, line_codigos in zip(f, f1, f2):
```

lo cual, además de ser más breve y más legible, tiene la ventaja de que no intenta cargar de antemano los contenidos de los ficheros en una lista, sino que se va leyendo tan solo una línea de cada vez (de cada uno de los tres ficheros) en cada iteración.

Esto consume mucha menos memoria y es preferible, especialmente en ficheros grandes. El uso de `readlines()` estaría justificado sólo si vas a necesitar iterar muchas veces por la lista de líneas, pues en ese caso el tenerla en memoria será mucho más veloz que leerlas del disco, o si vas a necesitar acceder a las líneas en cualquier orden distinto del secuencial, pues así tendrías índices para acceder a las líneas individuales.

En tu caso no se necesita eso, de modo que este segundo enfoque es mejor.

Comment: Efectivamente, funciona. Y sobre los iterables, terminarán al mismo tiempo porque los ficheros tienen la misma longitud. Muchas gracias por la explicación y la ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez He ampliado la respuesta con un detalle que puede resultarte interesante.